# Chef Recipe to configure multiple mpd instances

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, multiple-instances, chef-recipe, mpd

I try to create a chef cookbook to launch multiple mpd instances in my vagrant virtual box (using chef-solo).

I want to configure each instance in my Vagrantfile like this:

```
mpd: {
  channels: {
    mix: {
      name: 'mpd_mix',
      bind: '0.0.0.0',
      socket: '/home/vagrant/.mpd/socket/mix',
      port: '6600'
    },
    tech: {
      name: 'mpd_tech',
      bind: '0.0.0.0',
      socket: '/home/vagrant/.mpd/socket/tech',
      port: '6601'
    }
  }
}
```

So the recipe should take these settings and loop through them (creating an mpd instance for each channel).

This is what I currently have as a recipe:

```
package "mpd"

node.normal[:mpd][:channels].each_value do |channel|
    # create socket
    file channel[:socket] do
      action :touch
    end

    # trying to set the attributes for the config file and the service
    node.set[:mpd][:port] = channel[:port]
    node.set[:mpd][:db_file] = "/var/lib/mpd/tag_cache_" + channel[:name]
    node.set[:mpd][:bind_2] = channel[:socket]
    node.set[:mpd][:icecast_mountpoint] = "/" + channel[:name] + ".mp3"
    node.set[:mpd][:channel_name] = channel[:name]

    # create service
    service channel[:name] do
      service_name "mpd" # linux service command
      action :enable
    end

    # create the corresponding config file
    config_filename = "/etc/" + channel[:name] + ".conf"
    template config_filename do
      source "mpd.conf.erb"
      mode "0644"
      notifies :restart, resources(:service => channel[:name])
    end
end
```

I have several Problems with this:

1. Ist does not create a system service for each mpd instance, so I can do `sudo service mpd_mix start`. Why?
2. It does not use the `/etc/mpd_mix.conf` config file when launching mpd, because it still calls `/etc/init.d/mpd start` which uses `/etc/mpd.conf`. How can I change that, so it uses the correct config file for each mpd instance?
3. Adjusting the attributes for the creation of the config files does not work as expected (see the node.set part in the code above). Both config files, `/etc/mpd_tech.conf` and `/etc/mpd_mix.conf` use the tech channel attributes. Looks like the mix settings get overwritten somehow? How can I fix that?

I'd really appreciate some help on this as I am quite new to chef cookbooks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. Here is the relevant code part:

```
node[:mpd][:channels].each_value do |channel|

    # create socket
    file channel[:socket] do
      action :touch
    end

    # create init file
    init_filename = "/etc/init.d/" + channel[:name]
    template init_filename do
      variables :channel => channel
      source "mpd.init.erb"
      mode "0755"
    end

    # create service
    service channel[:name] do
      service_name channel[:name] # linux service command
      action :enable
    end

    # create config file
    config_filename = "/etc/" + channel[:name] + ".conf"
    template config_filename do
      variables :channel => channel
      source "mpd.conf.erb"
      mode "0644"
      notifies :restart, resources(:service => channel[:name])
    end

end
```

If you want to take a closer look, take a look at the complete cookbook repository on github: https://github.com/i42n/chef-cookbook-mpd/blob/master/recipes/default.rb